# How do I prevent AngularJS binding recursively?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select:

```
<select ng-model="p.value" ng-options="q for q in p.value">
<option value="">Select an animation</option>
</select>
```

Where `p.value` is `['AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC']` but when I select an option the select updates and shows a new bunch of options like:

```
<option>A</option>
<option>A</option>
<option>A</option>
<option>A</option>
<option>A</option>
```

I've obviously structured things wrong by using the same value in model and options. What is the correct way to do things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to separate the array of items and the model

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="p.selected" ng-options="q for q in p.value">
        <option value="">Select an animation</option>
    </select>
    {{p.selected}}
</div>
```

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.p = {
        value: ['AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC'],
        selected : null
    };
}
```

What is happening in your example is as soon as you select `AAAAA` `p.value` now references a list of characters and since `ng-options` is bound to the same `$scope` property the drop down list updates and produces your result you are seeing.

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/vrqy5/)**